# Is there a way to determine whether IEnumerable<T> is a sequence generator or true collection?

Tags: c#, linq

Let me provide an example:

Suppose i have a method:

```
public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    if (/* is lazy sequence */) throw ...

    // Do stuff...
}
```

And I want to guard against potentially infinite sequences.

Edit:

To elaborate, guarding against infinite collection is only one of the uses. As Jon mentioned. You can easily have infinite IList. Good point.

Other use might be to detect whether data is potentially unrepeatable. Like a random generator. True collection has data already in memory and iterating it twice will give me same data.

Comment: Well, then why not just take `ICollection<T>` (note: it could still be infinite, it could still be lazy, but it is a "collection").

Comment: What's the requirement for a "true collection"? Random access in O(1)? Is a linked list allowed? Is the result of File.ReadLines a true collection?

Comment: Since IEnumerable is just an interfaceb satisfiable by any mentioned thing (collection versus generator) I don't think so... although you could try some hack like calling `Last` but that would possibly be dangerous with a "generator" if it is infinite...

Comment: Ideally, you don't need such a check because you don't use any operations which require a finite total length. In the cases where you do need it, it may be better to require a differnt type that's guaranteed (or at least more likely) to be finite. Also consider that not everything lazy needs to be infinite.

Comment: Well because I don't need other stuff from ICollection<T>. Just enumerator.

Comment: @RonWarholic: Determining whether a lazy sequence (in particular, one using `yield return` - forgive me, I don't recall the C# terminology for such a block of code) is finite or not seems to be the halting problem indeed. Determining whether an object is actually a (strictly evaluated and hence finite) collection behind the interface may be *possible*, although it would likely require bypassing the type system.

Comment: You're saying that if someone writes the state machine implementation by hand, that's OK, but if the compiler writes it for you, that's bad?  That doesn't make any sense to me. **What problem are you really trying to solve here?**

Comment: Even if you managed to get the IL for the IEnumerable, figuring out if it were infinite or not would be equivalent to solving the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is undecidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators don't support the IEnumerable<>.Reset() method:

```
public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    sequence.Reset();
    // etc..
}
```

You get a NotSupportedException, which is good, with the Message "Specified method is not supported", which is tolerable.

Comment: Interesting but feels very hacky :-)

Comment: Well, the "this is impossible!" answer is very popular.  Maybe you should go with that.

Comment: @Hans +1 for snark and truth of implication.

Comment: Don't get why this is the accepted answer. Firstly, IEnumerable<T> doesn't have a Reset() method - only IEnumerator<T> does. And these are just interfaces. My implementation can do whatever it likes, including returning an infinite sequence, which you can reset to the first element (e.g. a random number generator with an initial seed). So no, it *is* impossible.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing that's guaranteed, no. You could see whether the sequence also implements `IList<T>` - that would prohibit iterator block implementations, but could still be a "virtual" list which continues forever, and it would also fail for some other finite non-iterator-block collections.

In terms of what you're trying to protect against, would a 2-billion-long sequence be okay for what you're trying to do? Would an extension method which threw an exception if you ended up with more than some "limit" (but do so lazily) work for you? (Something like Take, but which blew up at the end.)

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible.

The IEnumerable API cannot possibly tell you whether it is infinite or not. You can try casting it to ICollection to catch the common case where someone has passed you one of those, but if that's what you want then why don't you take an ICollection<...> object in the first place?