# .NET: Simple way to test if an IEnumerable is infinite, or prohibit infinite collections

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, infinity

I saw the post on [ways to handle an infinite IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740001/how-to-handle-an-infinite-ienumerable), but I didn't see a good answer for testing if an enumerable is infinite.

My end goal is to write a function for all collection types in .NET, but to safely traverse the whole collection without the risk of long wait times due to some infinite collection.

OPT1: I thought I might be able tell if an enumerable is infinite and throw an exception. However, I figure this would be the approach for .NET aggregate LINQ expressions (e.g. Max, Count) if it were possible.

- EDIT: As suspected, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796443/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-ienumerablet-is-a-sequence-generator-or-tr) was suggested that directly declares this option impossible

OPT2: Is there some other abstraction that supports most all enumerable types, but disallows infinite elements? `ICollection` looks promising, supports lists and arrays, but not Queues or many custom IEnumerables.

I'm also having a hard time determining if ICollection can be infinite or not.

Suggestions?

Comment: try out IReadOnlyCollection<T>, which is basically the same as IEnumerable + int Count property

Comment: How could you possibly tell if an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` is infinite? That would require knowledge of the implementation. `ICollection<T>` has a `Count` property: that would imply that the number of elements is known. Once cast to an `IEnumerable<T>`, that knowledge goes away and isn't available to whoever receives it (without peeking at the implementation).

Comment: @user1344783 I don't think most collections support IReadOnlyCollection. I'd end up pushing the infinity risk (and conversion) on the caller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to determine whether IEnumerable<T> is a sequence generator or true collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796443/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-ienumerablet-is-a-sequence-generator-or-tr)

Comment: @farlee2121, most concrete implementations in C# support IReadOnlyCollection<T>, List<T>, Collection<T>, HashSet<T>, you can name it, it probably supports. Don't use IList<T> because that is the worse interface and it should not exist.

Comment: @user1344783 Hmm, a good point. I think that may be as close as I can get

Comment: @gunr2171 That link is a great call out that I hadn't found. It does provide a more definitive answer to OPT1, but there is still the OPT2 with some alternative abstraction. I think user1344783's suggestion of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is probably about as good as I can hope for. It just seems like such a fundamental building block to have such a dangerous information hiding violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally running into the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). There's no general-purpose algorithm that can be used to determine whether or not a Turing-complete computation will ever complete.

You could have an `IEnumerable<int>` that enumerates all the digits in π. There's no way of telling if that function just keeps on going (as it should, according to mathematics), or only approximates π to a billion decimals.

> Is there some other abstraction that supports most all enumerable types, but disallows infinite elements?

I usually use [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1) for just that purpose. It's nothing but [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) with an extra [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1.count) property. That property strongly suggests that the collection has a finite length - particularly because `int` has a [MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue).

That said, a malicious implementer could trivially implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` as an infinite sequence by just lying and setting `Count` to, say, `0`, so there are no guarantees. But since *any* C# method could hypothetically block forever, I consider that par for the course.

I first [became aware of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` in 2013](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/07/20/linq-versus-the-lsp) and started using it soon thereafter. Using it is still a bit awkward at times, since so many other APIs return `IEnumerable<T>`. You can easily convert them to `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` with either [ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) or [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist), but it's still a little inconvenient at times.

Still, I've been [bitten by deferred execution](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/09/25/the-case-of-the-mysterious-comparison) enough times that I strongly favour `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.